# Fast directory conversion to file

Tags: linux, compression

I have a directory D that contains multiple files and folders and consumes a very large amount of disk space. Although I do not care much about disk space consumption, I want to convert D into a file as fast as possible. The first approach that came to mind was to use a compression tool however it is taking too long to finish.

Is there a faster way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As proposed, you can generate a compressed tarball. If this is still to slow, you could run multiple gzip instances in parallel to compress each single file and then pack it into a tarball. Whether this is faster depends very much in what is the limiting factor, I/O or CPU. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use tar command, with no compression

with `tar -cf` you can convert your folder to a file, with no compression process.

`tar -cf your_big_folder.tar /path/to/your/big/folder`

and finally you can convert it back to folder with

`tar -xf your_big_folder.tar`

Comment: did you make any comparison between `tar -cf` command and the `cp` command execution time in your system ?